# Timer tick not working in ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, timer

ASPX:

```
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick1">
            </asp:Timer>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Please format all the code and add some description of you are facing from this code

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also take the time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge).